# Get gender from noun using NLTK with German corpora

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm experimenting with NTLK. My question is if the library can detect the gender of a noun in German. I want to receive this information in order to determine if a text is written gender neutral. See here for more information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_languages_with_grammatical_gender

The underlying code categorizes my sentence, but I can't see any information about the gender of **"Mitarbeiter"**. My code so far:

```
sentence = """Der Mitarbeiter geht."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> tagged[0:6]
```

I haven't found any tools or scripts which accomplish this so far. Maybe there's also a better solution for my task.

Comment: Unless you have some code that demonstrates a particular problem, and that problem can be fixed with more code, this probably isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not able to see that information. I have to admit I'm a beginner in nlp.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being a beginner, it's great you're trying to learn. This just isn't a *programming* problem per-se unless you have some code.

Comment: You are right of course. I updated the question with the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Are you aware that NLTK assumes that your text is English if you don't specify otherwise? Even the `word_tokenize()` method accepts a `language='german'` parameter. If you POS-tag German text with an English tagger, you won't get anything useful.

Comment: I do know that. I specified a german corpora right before that snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe NLTK can do that out of the box for German. However, there are freely available morphological taggers for German which can do that for you, for example RFTagger:

http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/RFTagger/

It gives output like this:

```
Das     PRO.Dem.Subst.-3.Nom.Sg.Neut 
ist     VFIN.Sein.3.Sg.Pres.Ind 
ein     ART.Indef.Nom.Sg.Masc 
Testsatz    N.Reg.Nom.Sg.Masc 
.   SYM.Pun.Sent
```

However it is not in Python, so you would have to call it using subprocess. Another option would be to obtain a corpus with nouns tagged for German gender, such as the Tiger corpus:

http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/forschung/ressourcen/korpora/tiger.en.html

and train NLTK to recognize the genders, but I would expect RFTagger is a quicker/more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Pattern](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-de) purports to predict German noun gender with ~75% accuracy:

```
>>> from pattern.de import gender, MALE, FEMALE, NEUTRAL
>>> print gender('Katze')

FEMALE
```

Unfortunately it's only available in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this project which sounds promising regarding the question: https://github.com/aakhundov/deep-german .They predict from the character level which probably makes sense in a language like German. Although gender is not as easily detectable as in languages like Spanish, there is some regularities.

What also would work is to do relational parsing, get the pronouns referring to the object you want to classify and then see, whether they are female, male, or neutral. Maybe have a look at spacy for that, too.