# Get gender of nouns in a text?

Tags: python, nltk

I have a text with following category of names:

- People's nouns: "Mary", "John"
- Places/Objects nouns: "Empire State Building", "Warsaw"
- Devices: "ship", "airplane"

These nouns could be referred to with different pronouns in the text:

- "her", "he"
- "it", "it"
- "she", "it"

Is there a method to automatically "know" the pronoun that will be used for "Mary" or "John"?
I suspect it could be based on a look-up Table for every possible nouns, but I did not find such data.

I am interested in a solution for Python. NLTK might have a feature for that but I did not find it, but any other way could be a great hindsight!

A related question is:
[Get gender from noun using NLTK with German corpora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517201/get-gender-from-noun-using-nltk-with-german-corpora)

Comment: English does not assign gender to nouns. That would be silly!

Comment: @sintribu could you give an example to explain what did you mean.

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov Consider the two sentences using English and Spanish as an example. "Give me `the` book. I want to read `it`." "Give me `the` apple. I want to eat `it`".  Compared to Spanish: "Dame `el` libro. Yo `lo` quiero leer". "Dame `la` manzana. Yo `la` quiero comer" In Spanish (an many other languages) you change the way you reference nouns based on their arbitrary assignment of 'masculine' or 'feminine'. In English, in spite of all its flaws, has no distinction for inanimate objects.

Comment: Sorry I was in fact misleading on English not having gender for its pronouns
I was wondering if there was a possibility to identify "boy" as masculine and "girl" as feminine (with a dictionnary maybe)

Comment: Question edited to address the correct problem